# Javafx pie chart made with data from database does not display data

Tags: javafx, pie-chart, scenebuilder

I am new to Javafx and trying to read and understand tutorials on the internet of how to create charts with data from a Derby database using Scenebuilder.

I have managed to create a bar chart - which works fine.

But I am having some trouble getting the same data shown in a pie chart. Scene builder starts but no pie chart is shown.

What am I missing to have it shown as a pie chart?
Thanks for any help :-)

My code:

```js
     public class DocumentController implements Initializable {

  @FXML
  PieChart piechart;
  private Connection connexion;

  ArrayList < String > p = new ArrayList < String > ();
  ArrayList < Double > c = new ArrayList < > ();

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    loadData();
  }

  public void loadData() {
    String query = "select P, C From PIE "; //ORDER BY P asc
    ObservableList < PieChart.Data > piechartdata;
    piechartdata = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try {
      connexion = connectDB();
      ResultSet rs = connexion.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next()) {
        piechartdata.add(new PieChart.Data(rs.getString("P"), rs.getDouble("C")));
        p.add(rs.getString("P"));
        c.add(rs.getDouble("C"));
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }

  private Connection connectDB() {
    try {
      String dbString = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Pie";
      String user = "pie";
      String password = "pie";
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbString, user, password);
      System.out.println("Connection Ok");
      return conn;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set the data of your ObservableList to your pieChart

try something like this:

```
piechart.setData(piechartdata);
piechart.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Tried to set the data of my ObservableList as suggested - but unfortunately it still doesn't create the pie chart ...

Comment: Do you see at least the pieChart without the data or is it completly missing?

Comment: Scene builder starts and the title is shown but no pie chart.